# How to integrate PayU money Gateway in Android?

Tags: android, payment-gateway, payu

I am developing an Ecommerce app in which I want to integrate Payumoney payment gateway. Can someone help me with some procedure, link or tutorial, how to do so? Thanks.

Comment: 8K View and closed intresting

Comment: Did you implement this ? Can you share code pls if so ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have done Perfectly :) :) You have to edit `SuccessURL` and `FailureURL`:

Its Working for Me Perfectly.

```
public class PayUMoneyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * Adding WebView as setContentView
     */
    WebView webView;

    /**
     * Context for Activity
     */
    Context activity;
    /**
     * Order Id
     * To Request for Updating Payment Status if Payment Successfully Done
     */
    int mId; //Getting from Previous Activity
    /**
     * Required Fields
     */
    // Test Variables
    /*
    private String mMerchantKey = "FCyqqZ";
    private String mSalt = "sfBpGA8E";
    private String mBaseURL = "https://test.payu.in";
    */

    // Final Variables
    private String mMerchantKey = "Your Merchant Key";
    private String mSalt = "Salt";
    private String mBaseURL = "https://secure.payu.in";


    private String mAction = ""; // For Final URL
    private String mTXNId; // This will create below randomly
    private String mHash; // This will create below randomly
    private String mProductInfo = "Food Items"; //Passing String only
    private String mFirstName; // From Previous Activity
    private String mEmailId; // From Previous Activity
    private double mAmount; // From Previous Activity
    private String mPhone; // From Previous Activity
    private String mServiceProvider = "payu_paisa";
    private String mSuccessUrl = "your success URL";
    private String mFailedUrl = "Your Failure URL";


    boolean isFromOrder;
    /**
     * Handler
     */
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    /**
     * @param savedInstanceState
     */
    @SuppressLint({"AddJavascriptInterface", "SetJavaScriptEnabled"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /**
        * Setting WebView to Screen
        */
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview_for_payumoney);

        /**
         * Creating WebView
         */
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.payumoney_webview);

        /**
         * Context Variable
         */
        activity = getApplicationContext();

        /**
         * Actionbar Settings
         */
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        ab.setTitle(getString(R.string.title_activity_online_payment));

        /**
         * Getting Intent Variables...
         */
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {

            mFirstName = bundle.getString("name");
            mEmailId = bundle.getString("email");
            mAmount = bundle.getDouble("amount");
            mPhone = bundle.getString("phone");
            mId = bundle.getInt("id");
            isFromOrder = bundle.getBoolean("isFromOrder");

            Log.i(TAG, "" + mFirstName + " : " + mEmailId + " : " + mAmount + " : " + mPhone);

            /**
             * Creating Transaction Id
             */
            Random rand = new Random();
            String randomString = Integer.toString(rand.nextInt()) + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);
            mTXNId = hashCal("SHA-256", randomString).substring(0, 20);

            mAmount = new BigDecimal(mAmount).setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP).intValue();

            /**
             * Creating Hash Key
             */
            mHash = hashCal("SHA-512", mMerchantKey + "|" +
                    mTXNId + "|" +
                    mAmount + "|" +
                    mProductInfo + "|" +
                    mFirstName + "|" +
                    mEmailId + "|||||||||||" +
                    mSalt);

            /**
             * Final Action URL...
             */
            mAction = mBaseURL.concat("/_payment");

            /**
             * WebView Client
             */
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                    super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view,
                                               SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "SSL Error! " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    handler.proceed();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                    if (url.equals(mSuccessUrl)) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(PayUMoneyActivity.this, PaymentStatusActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("status", true);
                        intent.putExtra("transaction_id", mTXNId);
                        intent.putExtra("id", mId);
                        intent.putExtra("isFromOrder", isFromOrder);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else if (url.equals(mFailedUrl)) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(PayUMoneyActivity.this, PaymentStatusActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("status", false);
                        intent.putExtra("transaction_id", mTXNId);
                        intent.putExtra("id", mId);
                        intent.putExtra("isFromOrder", isFromOrder);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                }
            });

            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(2);
            webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webView.clearHistory();
            webView.clearCache(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
            webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
            webView.addJavascriptInterface(new PayUJavaScriptInterface(PayUMoneyActivity.this), "PayUMoney");

            /**
             * Mapping Compulsory Key Value Pairs
             */
            Map<String, String> mapParams = new HashMap<>();

            mapParams.put("key", mMerchantKey);
            mapParams.put("txnid", mTXNId);
            mapParams.put("amount", String.valueOf(mAmount));
            mapParams.put("productinfo", mProductInfo);
            mapParams.put("firstname", mFirstName);
            mapParams.put("email", mEmailId);
            mapParams.put("phone", mPhone);
            mapParams.put("surl", mSuccessUrl);
            mapParams.put("furl", mFailedUrl);
            mapParams.put("hash", mHash);
            mapParams.put("service_provider", mServiceProvider);

            webViewClientPost(webView, mAction, mapParams.entrySet());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Something went wrong, Try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Posting Data on PayUMoney Site with Form
     *
     * @param webView
     * @param url
     * @param postData
     */
    public void webViewClientPost(WebView webView, String url,
                                  Collection<Map.Entry<String, String>> postData) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append("<html><head></head>");
        sb.append("<body onload='form1.submit()'>");
        sb.append(String.format("<form id='form1' action='%s' method='%s'>", url, "post"));

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> item : postData) {
            sb.append(String.format("<input name='%s' type='hidden' value='%s' />", item.getKey(), item.getValue()));
        }
        sb.append("</form></body></html>");

        Log.d("TAG", "webViewClientPost called: " + sb.toString());
        webView.loadData(sb.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8");
    }

    /**
     * Hash Key Calculation
     *
     * @param type
     * @param str
     * @return
     */
    public String hashCal(String type, String str) {
        byte[] hashSequence = str.getBytes();
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            MessageDigest algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance(type);
            algorithm.reset();
            algorithm.update(hashSequence);
            byte messageDigest[] = algorithm.digest();

            for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
                String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
                if (hex.length() == 1)
                    hexString.append("0");
                hexString.append(hex);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException NSAE) {
        }
        return hexString.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            onPressingBack();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        onPressingBack();
    }

    /**
     * On Pressing Back
     * Giving Alert...
     */
    private void onPressingBack() {

        final Intent intent;

        if(isFromOrder)
            intent = new Intent(PayUMoneyActivity.this, ProductInCartList.class);
        else
            intent = new Intent(PayUMoneyActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(PayUMoneyActivity.this);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Warning");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Do you cancel this transaction?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    public class PayUJavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /**
         * Instantiate the interface and set the context
         */
        PayUJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public void success(long id, final String paymentId) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    mHandler = null;
                    Toast.makeText(PayUMoneyActivity.this, "Payment Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

### EDITED:

You can use https://www.payumoney.com/dev-guide/webcheckout/redirect.html now.

Comment: What is SuccessURL and failureURL. Could you please help me ?

Comment: You just have to put some web url which will use in `onPageFinished`

Comment: Can you give me example of URL?

Comment: Now they are giving API, you can try API - https://www.payumoney.com/dev-guide/

Comment: Hi,I am use some www.success..php and same as failur thay both work on test mode,and also have entry my PayUMoeny Account.but same code in live mode not working.have any change in test mode and live mode??

Comment: @bhoomika what you are getting as error in live mode? Any error?

Comment: @PratikButani Everything is working fine but how i do I get another full response , and what is the use of PayUJavaScriptInterface , its never triggered

Comment: Is that secure hard coding merchant key ,salt etc in android  ?.

Comment: What will happen if anyone theft? @sreekanthbalu

Comment: @PratikButani for testing its okay . But for production  I think  its recommended to keep salt , key on remote web server and generate hash to use it to post to payumoney .

Comment: Yeah you can store on firebase remote config.

Answer (score 9):

**Build Custom Integration**

> As per payumoney: If you are building your website from scratch you
>   need to make a post request to our `API`. Pass your `key` and other
>   `mandatory variable`. This also include the Success and Failure page
>   URL, where you wish to take your user on success and failure cases.
>
> **Step 1:** Create a store with any of our e-commerce platform partners.
>
> **Step 2:** Choose PayUMoney as Payment option.
>
> **Step 3:** Enter PayUMoney credentials and you are ready to go.

**Note:** You need to develop your own web services which take data from your client application and forward the request to payumoney server then take responses of callback after that your web services will notify you with result.

FlipKart, FreeCharge, Snapdeal etc they have their own url who will take responsibility to initiate the payment gateway,

So conclusion is that you need to support from your server team to initiate the payment and return the result back to your client application.

You can find the more information about payumoney and api [payumoney integration](https://www.payumoney.com/websiteintegration.html),

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4URmsDLhGXmfjFmbDQ5b2V0bVhjdTZMNExMVHRFMG1PRFFYeUV0LU9nSWU4U0pqaW00OU0&usp=drive_web&ddrp=1#  i need like this

Comment: hello i am using payu gateway in android app now can you please tell me what is the dfference between payu android sdk and custom browser do i have to use both or what ??

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way to integrate Payment gateway is to use a **webview** for your application.

You can see that most of the applications like **FlipKart, FreeCharge, Snapdeal** etc., use the same

Comment: I know that but sorry, but I don't know how to use a webview for application. Can you please provide some link or sample code to do so?

Comment: STEP 1
Complete a successful test transaction using the test credit card on PayU’s test server.
 
Merchant ID: gtKFFx
 
SALT: eCwWELxi
 
PayU Test URL: https://test.payu.in/_payment
 
Below are the test card details for doing a test transaction in the testing mode
 
Card Name – Any name
Card Number: 5123456789012346
CVV: 123
Expiry: may 2017
 
 
STEP 2
Once you have done the test transaction successfully. 
Merchant Key: XYZ
SALT: go to --> https://www.payu.in/index?returnUrl=salt#
 
The production URL is: https://secure.payu.in/_payment
For Integration Kit:

https://github.com/payu-india

Comment: in github.com you may select Payu php kit-->https://github.com/payu-india/Payu_php_kit

Comment: I would suggest you to download the documentation first from the above link its damn easy than..

Comment: @JaydeepGoswami Can you please explain in more detail that how to send data & which data to web view TEST TRANSACTION url?

Comment: Sorry for late reply..

Comment: As i said you.. First of all download the Library Files from http://github.com/payu-india and

Comment: There you'll find one Documentation File in .pdf format and one library file which you need to include in the file from where you are calling your payment gateway. After that simply call the method specified in the documentation along with the necessary parameters to be passed

Comment: in android native you can JSON Encode your data (i.e., Parameters) and send it to the server script ( .php or  .asp file)

Comment: hello i am using payu gateway in android app now can you please tell me what is the dfference between payu android sdk and custom browser do i have to use both or what ??

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did in my Application

```
public class PayYouMoneyFragment extends Fragment {

    /** The Constant PAYU_MONEY_URL. */
    private static final String PAYU_MONEY_URL = "https://www.payumoney.com/paybypayumoney/#/BCDCEAE6A98116CB48BDE55C440BC69D";

    /**
     * Instantiates a new pay you money fragment.
     */
    public PayYouMoneyFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    /**
     * The Class MyWebViewClient.
     */
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        /** The web view previous state. */
        private int webViewPreviousState;

        /** The page started. */
        private final int PAGE_STARTED = 0x1;

        /** The page redirected. */
        private final int PAGE_REDIRECTED = 0x2;

        /** The dialog. */
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.webkit.WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String)
         */
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.webkit.WebViewClient#onPageStarted(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String, android.graphics.Bitmap)
         */
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            webViewPreviousState = PAGE_STARTED;

            if (dialog == null || !dialog.isShowing())
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "",
                        "Loading Please Wait", true, true,
                        new OnCancelListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                // do something
                            }
                        });
        }

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.webkit.WebViewClient#onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String)
         */
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            if (webViewPreviousState == PAGE_STARTED) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                dialog = null;

            }

        }
    }

    /** The btn back. */
    Button btnBack;

    /** The webview. */
    WebView webview;

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.payumoney_fragment, container,
                false);


        webview = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.payu_webview);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        openURL();

        return rootView;
    }

    /**
     *  Opens the URL in a browser.
     */
    private void openURL() {
        webview.loadUrl(PAYU_MONEY_URL);
        webview.requestFocus();
    }

    public static Fragment newInstance() {
        return new PayYouMoneyFragment();
    }
}
```

and here is payumoney layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/help_webview"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:scrollbars="none"
/>
```

I have also uploaded generalized version on Github :-

https://github.com/hiteshsahu/Android-Universal-Web-Content-Loader

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete code guide to PayUMoney integration via web browser.

http://navraj.net/?p=22

Its been tested and deployed in a real world application

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. Please share the sample code bro. my mail - rranjithkumar100@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Go through this official link
[PayUMoney Developer site](http://developers.payu.com/en/mobile_sdk.html)

[GitHub Link For Android](https://github.com/PayU/paytouch-android)

I hope will be helpful

https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Android-SDK-Sample-App

Comment: NOTE: This is PayU for the USA, not India.

Comment: https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Android-SDK-Sample-App